# Windows Batch FOR loop

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop

I'm trying to write a batch script that would loop through each line from the output of another command. I am having trouble getting it to work. This is one example:

> FOR %i in ('wmic useraccount get name') DO ECHO %i

The command **wmic useraccount get name** gives me a list of users each on a separate line. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: You want `for /f`.  For more information, type `help for`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for` by itself won't execute a command. You need to add the `/f` argument.

`for /f %i in ('wmic useraccount get name') do echo %i`

See http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html or `for /?` from a command line.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to double up the percents too in a batch file and skip the unneeded header.

```dos
@ECHO OFF
FOR /F "SKIP=1 DELIMS=" %%a IN ('wmic useraccount get name') DO FOR %%i IN ("%%a") DO ECHO %%~i
```